# Send data from one module to another module with type safety

Tags: java, oop, module, data-exchange

**My Question**

What design would allow me to optionally pass data between two modules without the absence of type safety? Is such a thing possible?

**Explanation**

I have 2 modules derived from the class

```
abstract class Module {
    public abstract void init(App app);
    public abstract void exit(App app);
    public abstract void process(App app);
    public abstract void paint(Graphics g);
}
```

The App class tracks which module is the current module and allows that module to handle execution:

```
class App {
    private Map<Class<? extends Module>, Module> allModules = ...;
    private Module currentModule;

    //things to be used in modules
    private Canvas canvas;

    protected void start() {
        allModules.put(FirstModule.class, new FirstModule());
        //...

        currentModule = ...;
        currentModule.init(this);
    }

    protected void process() {
        currentModule.process(this);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        currentModule.paint(g);
    }

    public void switchModule(Class<? extends Module> module) {
        //perform validation
        Module next = allModules.get(module);

        currentModule.exit(this);
        currentModule = next;
        next.init(this);
    }

    //expose items that modules will use
    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

Now, the first module is responsible for gathering "settings" specified by the user; they will be shown checkboxes to choose from, then click a button which stores info about which checkbox was checked:

```
class First extends Module {
    private boolean firstBoxChecked, secondBoxChecked, thirdBoxChecked;

    public void init(App app) {
        canvas.addMouseListener(...);
    }

    public void process(App app) {
        if(buttonClicked) {
            app.switchModule(Second.class);
            //pass data to next module
        }
    }
}
```

So at some point during the execution of a module, it will switch the current module. There are times where I would want to pass data between the current module and the module I am switching to (from First to Second).

**My Attempt**

The only "efficient" way I can think of is to replicate Android's switching activities design (using an Intent like object):

```
ModuleSwitchAction action = new ModuleSwitchAction(Second.class);
action.put("firstBoxChecked", "true");
//...
app.switchModule(action);
```

The person in the other class would need to know the exact key names, without any warning at compile time if they messed something up. Is there a safer way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you want access to sub-type implementation differences from a super-type interface.  I'm not sure you are going to be able to do it without using a map, like you've done.  However, you can implement the key of the map with an enum type, at least providing some compile time type safety.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is "chain of responsibility" design pattern.
Check here - http://www.journaldev.com/1617/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial